# ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE in .NET app with winscard.dll

Tags: .net, windows, 64-bit, winscard

I'm creating a .NET Windows service to communicate with a smart card reader. The maincomponent is a Windows DLL called winscard.dll which I'm using with DLLImport attribute in the .NET code. Everything works fine on Windows XP 32 bit, but when i running it on **Windows 7 x64** i recive **0x6 ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE** result when calling **SCardTransmit**. The application (the service as command line app) can connect to the card reader but cannot read anything from the card.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried build your .NET application as a 32 BIT program rather than anycpu?

Comment: If i build it as 32 bit app, then:
Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write
 protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.CoTaskMemFree(IntPtr ptr)
   at SmartCard.SmartCardBase.SCardListReaderGroups(Int32 hContext, String& cGro
ups, Int32& nStringSize)
   at SmartCard.SmartCardBase.InitializeCardReader() in C:\Data\K7 Intranet\Smar
tCard\SmartCardBase.cs:line 152
   at SmartCard.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Data\K7 Intranet\SmartCard\Pro
gram.cs:line 14

Comment: It seems you aren't the only one (http://www.groupsrv.com/dotnet/about280604.html).  It doesn't much more information then you already have though.

Comment: The solution: use IntPtr instead of int (any type) and implement all winscard.dll method good, help: http://pinvoke.net/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have problems with **SCardEstablishContext** it will return *0* but handle also *0*. Use **IntPtr** instead of **Integer**:

```
Public Declare Function SCardEstablishContext Lib "Winscard.dll" (ByVal dwScope As Integer, _
                                                                      ByVal pvReserved1 As Integer, _
                                                                      ByVal pvReserved2 As Integer, _
                                                                      ByRef phContext As IntPtr) As Integer
```

phContext will be store valid value in Windows x64 (Windows 8 x64 and Windows 2008 via RDP tested). Also replace other "Integer" to "IntPtr" when it used as handle.

```
Public Declare Function SCardConnect Lib "Winscard.dll" Alias "SCardConnectA" (ByVal hContext As IntPtr, _
                                                                                   ByVal szReaderName As String, _
                                                                                   ByVal dwShareMode As Integer, _
                                                                                   ByVal dwPrefProtocol As Integer, _
                                                                                   ByRef hCard As IntPtr, _
                                                                                   ByRef ActiveProtocol As IntPtr) As Integer
```

Comment: Yes this was the solution.

Comment: Thanks brother, this worked perfect. Just replace all handle and context types to IntPtr.